# Carrying Metal gifts to USA (elephant, eagle & peacock) for my friends

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage, tsa, artworks

I am travelling to Chicago (Illinois, USA)  for about 20 days from Bangalore, Karnataka, India.

I have few friends in Chicago, to whom I would like to give some nice gifts.

My gifts are as follows :

1. Metallic Elephant where  height - 8cm, length - 15cm and width - 4cm
2. Metallic Peacock where height - 5cm, length - 19cm and width - 3cm
3. Metallic Eagle where height - 10cm, length - 8cm and width - 4cm

I am thinking to add these on my check in luggage during my travel.

I have added pictures for reference

Overall cost of these items is approximately 80$ or INR 5300

[image]
[image]
[image]

I would like to know if the TSA officer or any security officer is going to stop me and confiscate these items during the security check? what is my best option available?

Comment: Unless they are filled with drugs there is very unlikely to be any issues. Nice gifts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would i have to carry bill receipt ? should i declare these items in the form given by security officer?

Comment: If you want to be sure to be allowed through, declare them and bring the receipts.

Comment: you will have NO PROBLEM with these in checked.  in hand luggage - I'm not sure but you'd probably be ok!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the [U.S. Customs and Border Protection](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/975/kw/Duty%20Free%20allowances%20for%20visitors/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ3NzIzMzU4Ny9zaWQvQUtSSmNRMW4%3D):

> **As a visitor to the United States what are my exemptions on gifts for family and friends?**
>
> As a non-resident, you are allowed up to $100 worth of merchandise,
>   free of duty and internal revenue tax, as gifts for other people. To
>   claim this exemption, you must remain in the United States for at
>   least 72 hours, and the gifts must accompany you.
>
> This $100 gift exemption, or any part of it, can be claimed only once
>   every six months. You may include 100 cigars within the gift
>   exemption, but alcoholic beverages may not be included. The cigars may
>   not be of Cuban origin.

So Customs won't care about those gifts. TSA won't mind them either as they don't remotely look like weapons.

Comment: `they don't remotely look like weapons` You underestimate a determined assailant.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Luckily for the OP, so do most people (which includes the vast majority of law/regulation makers and TSA agents).

Comment: 'The cigars may not be of Cuban origin.' Has that not been changed recently with Obama repealing the embargo on Cuban goods?

Comment: The tail on the peacock looks quite pointy, it could look like a weapon.

Comment: The absolute worse that will happen, is that they _may_ be put through the scanner individually. That's about all. Pack them securely in your checked-in luggage, and have a safe trip.

Comment: @SGR [That is indeed the case](http://www.highsnobiety.com/2016/10/14/cuban-cigar-rum-ban-lifted/)